# Copy paste from clipboard not working anymore in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, clipboard, simulator

For me and some of my colleges the ability to paste text inside iOS simulator is not working anymore. We are not sure why this happened but some think that once we ran simulator with iOS 16 then the copy/paste functionality stopped working.

It doesn't paste on any app in the simulator nor even on native ios Search bar. I know for at least 3 other colleagues mentioned this started to happen on their system too.
Not even trying to paste with long press option on the textfield, "Paste" option doesn't appear.

This seems a general issue. I was wondering if this is a known bug or if someone found a workaround to make this work again?

Comment: Where are you copying from and what version of Xcode? I have no trouble copying from anywhere on my Mac and then pasting into my iOS app running in a simulator on the same Mac. I can even copy from something on a real iOS device and paste into my app running in a simulator when the real iOS device and Mac are on the same network.

Comment: I have both Xcode 13.1 and Xcode 14.1, none of them are working to copy paste inside simulator. I was trying to copy from Notes app. I tried multiple simulators. iOS15, iOS13 and iOS16 multiple models and none of them are working.

Comment: not even trying to paste with long press option on the textfield. simply nothing gets pasted

Comment: i mean.. the "Paste" option doesn't even appear

Comment: As I said, it works just fine for me. Perhaps you have code in place that is preventing the Paste menu from appearing. Does `Cmd-V` work to paste into the simulator? Can you paste into other apps in the simulator? If so then your app is doing something to prevent the pasting.

Comment: nope . it doesn't paste on any app in the simulator nor even on native ios Search bar. I know for at least 3 other colleagues mentioned this started to happen on their system too

Comment: You should add those extra details into your question to make it clear it's a general simulator issue and not related to any specific app your are developing.

Answer (score -1):

Simulator has removed the copy and paste from mac feature. You may not use it anymore.